# What are these brown patches on my acanthocereus tetragonus (fairy castle cactus)?

Tags: diagnosis, cactus

I've had this pair of fairy castle cacti for several years now, and they've done fairly well. However, I noticed today that they have developed brown patches over most of their stems and a few areas have a sort of crackled look. I can't say exactly how long it took for this to develop, but I didn't notice it on the last watering (6-8 weeks ago).

[image: brown patches and "crackling" (lower left and middle right) on fairy castle cactus]

in some areas it looks "built up", like it could be chipped off (though I haven't tried). There are also a few very dark spots that almost look burnt, except they are on the side facing away from the window.

[image: "burnt"-looking spots on fairy castle cactus 1]

[image: "burnt"-looking spots on fairy castle cactus 2]

Any ideas on what is wrong with them, and what I can do about it (natural methods only please - I don't use commercial gardening products)?

Comment: I was tempted to say corking (a natural process on some cacti such as prickly pears), but that is usually on the oldest bits of the stems - you've got it on the tips and in spots. So I suspect it is some kind of infection.  The cuticle is then dying or if you are lucky responding in a similar way as corking so as to protect the plant.

Comment: good tips, thanks. Searching for corking did lead me to some helpful search results I wasn't getting by just searching the description of the problem, so I'm a little closer to figuring this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to me that you've got more than one thing going on here.  "Corking" for sure and in the lowest photo of spots, that looks like physical damage. I've found a great site for you to pursue and more closely identify your problems/questions.  Other general information I think all cactus owners should know.  Let us know what you decided and what you plan to do, before you do it and we'll be better able to help. 
[cactus fungus and disease](http://cactiguide.com/cactipests/#fungus)

Comment: Stormy, would you consider adding more information on this? Also, part of the question was "*what I can do about it (natural methods only please - I don't use commercial gardening products)?*". You should try to cover that in your answer, as well.

Comment: What do to about it? Nothing, there is nothing to do with a plant that has corking. It will never regrow "normally", it's a permanent condition. The way forward is to use the resources presented to try to determine what caused it. I wouldn't characterize the pictured corking as "natural". It was caused by something, cold weather, insects, sunburn, physical damage, etc.